# How to get array of html object in data() in vue3

Tags: arrays, vuejs3

I want to do something like this.
But when I try to get that data it is still an empty array

```
data(){
        return {
          sections: [...document.querySelectorAll(".section")]
        }
   },
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that in the first place? Also, this is probably run before the template is generated in the DOM. Tried in `mounted()`?

Comment: You might be interested to learn about https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html